# Powershell Querying Code

Tags: powershell

I am having issues writing some PowerShell code.

I am trying to run a query against Active Directory which will export all groups, members of the groups, email addresses, and SIDs of each user to a CSV file.

It has to be recursive so that it searches groups within groups.

Thank you so much for the help! I am new at this.

The code I currently have only displays names of a specific group:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$Group = Get-ADGroupMember -identity “Group distinguishedname” -Recursive
$Group | get-aduser -Properties mail |select name,samaccountname,mail |export-csv -path $scriptPath\Members.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to shortness of time I'll answer like so:

You could work along the lines of first ferreting out all the groups into a variable similar to:

`$Groups = Get-ADGroup ...`

Then you iterate over the `$Groups` object in an fashion similar to:

```
$Groups | Foreach-Object `
{
        $CurrentGroup = $_
    $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $CurrentGroup ...

    # Build CSV string here with output from both
    # both $CurrentGroup and $Members
    # and additional data you might want to pull

    # Write CSV string to file here or add it to an array
    # to print to file after the looping.
}
```

Hopefully that nudges you in a workable direction, I'll take a look at how far you got and help you out as time allows me.

Comment: import-module activedirectory

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"' 
Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    Write-Host $G.Name
    Write-Host "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
     Get-ADGroupMember $G | select name,samaccountname,mail,SID 
}
export-csv -path $scriptPath\Members4.csv -NoTypeInformation           This is how far I have gotten. For some reason it wont export data correctly.

Comment: 'import-module activedirectory

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"' 
Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    Write-Host $G.Name
    Write-Host "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
     Get-ADGroupMember $G | select name,samaccountname,mail,SID 
}
export-csv -path $scriptPath\Members4.csv -NoTypeInformation'

Comment: Nice! I'll take a proper look as soon as I am able. You would likely need a way of iterating to get the nested group memberships reporting right too, apart from the bit about exporting correctly. Am away on vacation so it's a bit tricky, but I'll be back :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing it this way around is that your results are not guaranteed to be unique. You could and probably do have users who are members of multiple groups. Should this happen, you'll find you have duplicate entries in your report.

Another problem is that you will end up with other objects such as computers and groups in your results. It is possible to filter these out. Overall, it gets quite complicated trying to display the current group and user information on the same line.

AD user objects have a `memberOf` attribute. If you just list all AD users and the relevant attributes you're after (including the `memberOf` attribute), you will have a much cleaner report and it will be much quicker to generate.

So your script would look more like this:

```
# Only required if using Powershell 2.0
Import-Module Active Directory

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mail,memberOf |
    Select Name,SamAccountName,Mail,SID,memberOf |
    Export-CSV $script_path\members.tsv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"
```

The only problem with this solution is that the memberOf field gives the DN of the groups (each containing commas, each seprated by commas also), so this is a tab delmited document instead. Once you have a TSV you can sort and filter it as you wish.

Not the best solution, but it gets quite complicated otherwise. Since you are new to this, it's best to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes, that is a neat idea. I interpreted the question to actually be group centric rather than user centric, so duplicate user entries, as well as groups which only contain groups, or which have no members were to be listed too. Perhaps @Mark could clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

By using the add-member cmdlet we keep the PsObject and add the group information that we need to export. Keeping the data in a PsObject makes it easy to output.

```
$adGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter *

foreach ($grp in $adGroups){
    Write-Host "Processing $($grp.DistinguishedName)"

    #get the memebers of the group
    $grpMembers = Get-ADGroupMember $grp | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq "user"} | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

   foreach ($member in $grpMembers){
        #Get user information
        $user = get-aduser $member -Properties mail

        #Add group name and DN to the object
        Add-Member -InputObject $user -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Group -Value $grp.Name -Force
        Add-Member -InputObject $user -MemberType NoteProperty -Name GroupDn -Value $grp.DistinguishedName -Force

        #Output user to CSV
        $user | select name, samAccountName, SID, distinguishedName, Group, GroupDn | Export-Csv "c:\Windows\temp\groupMembership.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

***NOTE: This only outputs user objects***